# SIGSEGV with QMainWindow singleton

Tags: qt, qt4, singleton, segmentation-fault, qmainwindow

The application I am writting as unique instantiation of some classes which have to be accessible easily. For that i use singletons.

For exemple my Core is defined as :

```
class Core : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Core();
        ~Core();
        static Core& getCore()
        {
            static Core mycore;
            return mycore;
        }
        (...)
};
```

and it works just great. However I tried to do the same with my MainWindow class, which interits from QMainWindow. I need that in order to access methods such as geometry() from other objects

However Core works great, MainWindow makes error when clossing the programe. The main window destructor is called and executed apparently once ( debug using qDebug() ) but i still have a SIGSEGV signal. What's happening? How to solve it?

Here is the code of MainWindow

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
        static MainWindow& getUi()
        {
            static MainWindow myUi;
            return myUi;
        }
    public slots:
        void refreshImage();
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&appCore(), SIGNAL(refreshed()), this, SLOT(refreshImage()));
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

And the main code

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
try
{
    appCore().setDevice(MDMA::Kinect);
    appUi().show();
    return app.exec();
} catch(MDMA::exn e) {
    (...)
}
```

where appCore and appUi are macros for Core::getCore and MainWindow::getUi()

Comment: "And it works just great" no it doesn't. Stop using singletons; they're worthless.

Comment: how whould you do then ???

Answer (score 2):

This crash probably results from your `QApplication` being destroyed before the `MainWindow`.

If you cannot pass your `MainWindow` via other ways to the code where it is needed (e.g. as argument or via `QObjecg::parent()`), you could employ a technique similar to what `QApplication` does with it's [`instance`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#instance) method (a non-owning global reference):

Construct your `MainWindow` as an ordinary local variable on the stack, *after* the `QApplication`. Then set a global pointer (maybe better a [`QPointer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpointer.html); e.g. a static member of `MainWindow`), which you initially initialize to `0`, to `this` in the constructor of `MainWindow`. You can also check if it was already initialized here to enforce the uniqueness. Via a public accessor method (`instance`?) for the global pointer, you can access the class from everywhere while ensuring destruction before `QApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make singletone, try to use general technics, for example, as described here:
http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Singleton_pattern

Hope, lot of questions will dissappear after reading all of that article.

As for me, there is nice and simple realization of singletone.

Good luck!

Comment: the link is broken